# Tablesorter non-functional after load even though its placed in the callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tablesorter

I had a similar question [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797099/tablesorter-becomes-non-functional-after-jquery-page-load) and at the time placing the tablesorter call in the `.load()` callback worked, but now, after what I thought was unrelated changes, its devolved to its former behavior: It sorts initially, but after the load clicking on the column headers has no effect. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** It looks as though the tablesorter function works when the commented code is commented out, but not when it isn't, but I can't see why the commented code affects the uncommented code. Apologies for changing the scope of the question.

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
        $('#status-tables').load('/dashboard/index #status-tables');
    }, 5000);

//var clicks = true

//$("#application-name-label").animate({
//    "color": "black"
//}, 1000);

//$("#refresh-5-sec").addClass("pressed-button")

//$("#refresh-button").on("click", function(event) {
//   var buttonGroup = $(this).next();

//if(clicks) {
//    $(buttonGroup).fadeOut(
//      function() {
//        $(this).parent().css('padding-right', '235px');
//        $(this).parent().animate({
//           paddingRight: "15"
//        }, 300);
//        clicks = false;
//      });
//  } else {
//      $(buttonGroup).fadeIn();
//      clicks = true;
//  };
//});


    $("#refresh-buttons").on("click", "button", function(event) {

        var interval = 0;

        switch(event.target.id)  {
          case "refresh-off" :
                interval = 50000000;
                $(this).parent().children().removeClass("pressed-button");
                $(this).addClass("pressed-button");
                break;

          case "refresh-5-sec" :
              interval = 5000;
              $(this).parent().children().removeClass("pressed-button");
              $(this).addClass("pressed-button");
              break;

          case "refresh-30-sec" :
              interval = 30000;
              $(this).parent().children().removeClass("pressed-button");
              $(this).addClass("pressed-button");
              break;

          case "refresh-60-sec" :
              interval = 60000;
              $(this).parent().children().removeClass("pressed-button");
              $(this).addClass("pressed-button");
              break;
        }

        if (interval != 0)
        {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = setInterval(function(){
                $('#status-tables').load('/dashboard/index #status-tables', function(){$("#workstation-table").tablesorter(); });
            }, interval);
        }

    });

  $("#workstation-table").tablesorter();

});
```

HTML (from HAML template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Webui</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="YMkodi1Yy31wpZOA2dGdgbltM8M36Tiffo9PCMRlfsA=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<div class='whole-page'>
  <div class='container'>
    <h1 class='hero-unit' id='application-title'>
      <div class='row-fluid'>
        <div class='span1' id='replication-server'>
          <img alt="Cog logo" src="/assets/cog_logo.png" />
          <img alt="Crs" src="/assets/crs.png" />
          Replication Server
          <div class='span1 pull-right' id='refresh-label'>
            <button class='btn' id='refresh-button'>Refresh Rate</button>
            <div class='btn-group' id='refresh-buttons'>
              <button class='btn btn-default' id='refresh-off'>Off</button>
              <button class='btn btn-default' id='refresh-5-sec'>5 sec</button>
              <button class='btn btn-default' id='refresh-30-sec'>30 sec</button>
              <button class='btn btn-default' id='refresh-60-sec'>60 sec</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <small id='application-name-label'>Status Dashboard</small>
    </h2>
    <div id='status-tables'>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <h3>Reports</h3>
        <div class='panel' id='report-table-panel'>
          <a class='accordion-toggle' data-target='#collapse-cidne' data-toggle='collapse'>CIDNE</a>
        </div>
        <div class='uncollapse in' id='collapse-cidne'>
          <table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered' id='report-table'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th id='table-header'>Source</th>
                <th id='table-header'>Type</th>
                <th id='table-header'>Count</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                ullam
              </td>
              <td>
                1,578,262
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                adipisci
              </td>
              <td>
                5,828,812
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                ullam
              </td>
              <td>
                2,970,946
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                quae
              </td>
              <td>
                7,918,186
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                quae
              </td>
              <td>
                6,331,230
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                vero
              </td>
              <td>
                9,082,103
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                ullam
              </td>
              <td>
                9,681,110
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                vero
              </td>
              <td>
                5,572,147
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                quia
              </td>
              <td>
                502,000
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                quae
              </td>
              <td>
                6,517,368
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                vero
              </td>
              <td>
                8,603,032
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                ullam
              </td>
              <td>
                8,716,460
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class='panel' id='report-table-panel'>
          <a class='accordion-toggle' data-target='#collapse-dcgs' data-toggle='collapse'>DCGS</a>
        </div>
        <div class='uncollapse in' id='collapse-dcgs'>
          <table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered' id='report-table'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th id='table-header'>Source</th>
                <th id='table-header'>Type</th>
                <th id='table-header'>Count</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Reiciendis
                </td>
                <td>
                  3,286,731
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Sunt
                </td>
                <td>
                  3,269,134
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Reiciendis
                </td>
                <td>
                  6,720,385
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Reiciendis
                </td>
                <td>
                  4,965,628
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Dicta
                </td>
                <td>
                  4,318,889
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Reiciendis
                </td>
                <td>
                  1,060,083
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Sunt
                </td>
                <td>
                  7,625,906
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Reiciendis
                </td>
                <td>
                  2,863,118
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Dicta
                </td>
                <td>
                  1,294,952
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  DCGS
                </td>
                <td>
                  Dicta
                </td>
                <td>
                  3,809,659
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-5'>
        <h3 id='workstation-title'>Workstations</h3>
        <div class='span-1'>
          <div id='sort-instructions'>(click column name to sort)</div>
        </div>
        <table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered' id='workstation-table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th id='table-header'>Name</th>
              <th id='table-header'>Downloaded</th>
              <th id='table-header'>Available</th>
              <th id='table-header'>Last Connect</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                dignissimos
              </td>
              <td>
                19,787
              </td>
              <td>
                1,278,685
              </td>
              <td>
                2013-09-01 07:59:58
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                sint
              </td>
              <td>
                23,634
              </td>
              <td>
                5,673,401
              </td>
              <td>
                2013-09-15 12:43:55
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                magnam
              </td>
              <td>
                31,465
              </td>
              <td>
                4,094,304
              </td>
              <td>
                2013-09-03 09:56:55
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                enim
              </td>
              <td>
                36,566
              </td>
              <td>
                4,579,378
              </td>
              <td>
                2013-09-01 08:09:41
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                quos
              </td>
              <td>
                28,638
              </td>
              <td>
                5,486,033
              </td>
              <td>
                2013-07-16 01:56:16
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                voluptatibus
              </td>
              <td>
                15,129
              </td>
              <td>
                2,612,705
              </td>
              <td>
                2013-07-14 04:35:11
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                ullam
              </td>
              <td>
                17,624
              </td>
              <td>
                3,661,141
              </td>
              <td>
                2013-07-10 10:33:42
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                et
              </td>
              <td>
                52,962
              </td>
              <td>
                3,951,956
              </td>
              <td>
                2013-07-10 09:24:28
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-3'>
        <h3>Source</h3>
        <table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered'>
          <tr>
            <th id='table-header'>Type</th>
            <th id='table-header'>Name</th>
            <th id='table-header'>Status</th>
            <tr>
              <td>
                CIDNE
              </td>
              <td>
                http://lang.com/jarrett_reynolds
              </td>
              <td>
                <div id='service-down'></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                DCGS
              </td>
              <td>
                http://mraz.net/coy
              </td>
              <td>
                <div id='service-up'></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

HAML (just in case its helpful):

```
.whole-page
  .container
    %h1#application-title.hero-unit
      .row-fluid
        .span1#replication-server
          = image_tag "cog_logo.png"
          = image_tag "crs.png"
          Replication Server
          .span1.pull-right#refresh-label
            %button.btn#refresh-button Refresh Rate
            .btn-group#refresh-buttons
              %button.btn.btn-default#refresh-off Off
              %button.btn.btn-default#refresh-5-sec 5 sec
              %button.btn.btn-default#refresh-30-sec 30 sec
              %button.btn.btn-default#refresh-60-sec 60 sec
    %h2
      %small#application-name-label Status Dashboard
    #status-tables
      .col-md-4
        %h3 Reports
        #report-table-panel.panel
          %a.accordion-toggle{ :data => { :toggle => "collapse", :target => "#collapse-cidne"} } CIDNE
        #collapse-cidne.uncollapse.in
          %table#report-table.table.table-striped.table-hover.table-bordered
            %thead
              %tr
                %th#table-header Source
                %th#table-header Type
                %th#table-header Count
            %tbody
            - @reports.each do |report|
              - if report[:source] == "CIDNE"
                %tr
                  %td
                    = report[:source]
                  %td
                    = report[:type]
                  %td
                    = report[:count]
        #report-table-panel.panel
          %a.accordion-toggle{ :data => { :toggle => "collapse", :target => "#collapse-dcgs"} } DCGS
        #collapse-dcgs.uncollapse.in
          %table#report-table.table.table-striped.table-hover.table-bordered
            %thead
              %tr
                %th#table-header Source
                %th#table-header Type
                %th#table-header Count
            %tbody
              - @reports.each do |report|
                - if report[:source].blank?

                - elsif report[:source] == "DCGS"
                  %tr
                    %td
                      = report[:source]
                    %td
                      = report[:type]
                    %td
                      = report[:count]
      .col-md-5
        %h3#workstation-title Workstations
        .span-1
          #sort-instructions (click column name to sort)
        %table#workstation-table.table.table-striped.table-hover.table-bordered
          %thead
            %tr
              %th#table-header Name
              %th#table-header Downloaded
              %th#table-header Available
              %th#table-header Last Connect
          %tbody
            - @workstations.each do |workstation|
              %tr
                %td
                  = workstation[:name]
                %td
                  = workstation[:downloaded]
                %td
                  = workstation[:available]
                %td
                  = workstation[:last_connect]
      .col-md-3
        %h3 Source
        %table.table.table-striped.table-hover.table-bordered
          %tr
            %th#table-header Type
            %th#table-header Name
            %th#table-header Status
            - @data_sources.each do |data_source|
              %tr
                %td
                  = data_source[:type]
                %td
                  = data_source[:name]
                %td
                  - if data_source[:status] == "UP"
                    #service-up
                  - else
                    #service-down
```

Comment: You are using two load() methods, one you are reinitializing tablesorter, one not.

Comment: @A.Wolff that was the root of the problem. If you post an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for pointing out what should have been plain to see :).

Comment: That's ok, glad you have fixed your issue ;)